# Why can I use size_t without defining it?

Tags: c, size-t

```
int main(void)
{
    size_t a = 20;
    unsigned int b = 0;

    b = a;

    return 0;
}
```

no header files are included.

i wrote this in cmd

> clang -std=c89 -W -Wall -pedantic-errors *.c

why does it compile and run without problems?

I am using clang 13.0.1. (LLVM-13.0.1-win32.exe)

[image]

linker is using VS
[image]

i don't know where to put this
"#error Compiled indeed"
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find commandlines which do show errors?

Comment: As a paranoid double check that you are actually compiling the file you look at, please insert a `#error Compiled indeed.` and try to compile again. If you do not get an error even then, something is fishy.

Comment: MSVC 64-bit compiler complains about loss of data (`size_t` is larger than `unsigned int`). Their older 32-bit compiler doesn't know any `size_t` type. But with `#include <stdio.h>` the 32-bit one compiles cleanly (and `size_t` is the same size as `unsigned int`). Both compilers have *some* problem with the posted code.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/16o3hs774

Comment: Only compile the file in question, now you are compiling all c files in the directory (*.c)

Comment: Try `clang -E main.c` --- https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#actions

Comment: You just learned that showing code details in comments is unhelpful. Please [edit9 the question to express that. As it is, it is unreadable.

Comment: Can you confirm seeing the "Compiled indeed." message?

Comment: where can i see "Compiled indeed"

Comment: It doesn't compile because I put `#error Compiled indeed`, but it seems to compile if I don't. @Yunnosch

Comment: do you know why the results are different??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe does not happen with clang on linux systems, but it does with the x64 version of MSVC as can be verified on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/h4nPGjhxs).

It looks like `size_t` is a built-in type for this compiler.

The compiler accepts this built-in to be redefined as long as the definition is

```
typedef unsigned long long size_t;
```

Anything else causes an error. As commented by *Jonathan Leffler*, C11 and later allows you to define a `typedef` more than once as long as the definitions are the same (and not for a variably-modified type).

Comment: C11 and later allows you to define a typedef more than once as long as the definitions are the same (and not for a variably-modified type).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: good point. Answer amended. Do you know if `size_t` is predefined in C++ ? It would make sense for `size_t`, `ptrdiff_t` and `wchar_t` to be predefined as they are primitive types produced by simple expressions: `sizeof(0)`, `q - p`, `L'a'`...